# How to remove comma, double quotes in postgresql output

Tags: postgresql, function

I have two columns: URL and Name. I i need to concatenate to columns in one variable,
but in the output i want to remove the double quotes and comma.

```
 id |          url           |      name      | description | last_update
----+------------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------
 18 | http://www.oreilly.com | O'Reilly Media |             |
 19 | https://www.google.com | Google         |             | 2013-06-01
(2 rows)
```

```
create or replace Function hello_world()
RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE 
v_name_url VARCHAR;
BEGIN
select (name, url) INTO v_name_url from links e where id = 18;

RETURN v_name_url;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Output

```
                 hello_world
----------------------------------------------
 ("O'Reilly Media",http://www.oreilly.com)
(1 row)
```

How to remove the double quotes and comma from the output?

```
            hello_world
--------------------------------------
 O'Reilly Media http://www.oreilly.com
(1 row)
```

Comment: I notice that you have asked several questions but have not accepted answers. I'd highly encourage that you give closure to your questions by marking one of the answers as accepted, if suitable. You can click the tick mark besides an answer of your choice. That'll help others find your question and acceptable answer.

Comment: You put a record of two columns in a single text field. That's why you get these extra quotes and a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your stored procedure to something like this:

```
drop function hello_world();

create or replace function hello_world()
RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE 
v_name_url VARCHAR;
BEGIN
select concat(name, ' ', url) INTO v_name_url from links e where id = 18;

RETURN v_name_url;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Your results will be like so:

```
select hello_world();

              hello_world              
---------------------------------------
 O'Reilly Media http://www.oreilly.com
(1 row)
```